# Jenkins Pipeline Job prints twice PowerShell's output

Tags: powershell, jenkins, logging

I ran into a troubling issue. A powershell script's output gets printed twice on Jenkins. This is the code in pipeline:
[image]

This is what gets printed in the logs:

[image]

I have no clue on why this is happening. Tested with a FreeStyle job and the output there is okay. Any leads on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following.
The PowerShell step in the pipeline stage starts x32bit PowerShell, and inside this session I open x64bit PowerShell. When using Write-Host, now there are two hosts, the 64 bit one and the 32 bit one. This is the reason of the double log. The solution would be to either open the x64 bit PowerShell from a script block or a sh step, or to pipe the x64 output into Null.